# Dynamic component replacement not working with vue-router after update to v3.0.1

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

dynamic component replace on vue-router is not working anymore after i updated vue-router to version 3.0

my code was like this, and the idea is to replace the component on click event

```
loadmodule(Name, uri) {
  router.addRoutes([
    {
      path: "/dynamicroute",
      component: function(resolve) {
        require(["../modules/" + uri + ".vue"], resolve);
      }
    }
  ]);
  router.push("/dynamicroute");
  console.log("Dynamic Route"+Name+" has been invoked URI " + uri);
}
```

no error is displayed on the console , its just once one component is loaded it cannot replace it with next click

Comment: If you are using webpack, try the following `component: () => import(\`../modules/${uri}.vue\`);`

Comment: ya the thing is i cannot use es6 with laravel, not sure why but it throws Syntax Error: Unexpected token  at import() word

Comment: I just come to know that on vue router i cannot start route path with number like /000comp1 /001comp2 :( but it works like /comp001 /comp002

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just come to know that in vue-router i **cannot** start route path with number like `/000comp1 /001comp2` :( but it works like `/comp001 /comp002`